# Test class for trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I have below trigger on feeditem which i tried for test class to write am unable to cover all the fields in the trigger .because of that unable to meet criteria of salesforce.

```
trigger CountChatterPostsOnCase on FeedItem (before insert, after Insert ) {
    String caseKeyPrefix = Case.sObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix();
    set<ID> caseIDs = new set<ID>();
    for (FeedItem f : trigger.new){
        String parentId = f.parentId;
        if(parentId != null && parentId.startsWith(caseKeyPrefix) && f.Visibility == 'AllUsers'){
            caseIDs.add(f.parentId);
        }
    }
    if(!caseIDs.IsEmpty()){
        list<case> cslist =[Select f1 , f2 from Case where id = :caseIDs];
        for (case cs:cslist) {
            cs.f1 = cs.f1 == null? 1 : cs.f1 + 1;
            cs.f2 = cs.f2 == null? 1 : cs.f2 + 1;
        }
        update cslist;

    }
}

@isTest Public with sharing class CountChatterPostsOnCaseTest {

Public static testmethod testCountChatterPostsOnCase()
{
  Contact cont = new Contact();
         cont.NTID__c ='test1';
         cont.Last Name ='demo';
         cont.Country__c ='ABC';
         cont.Email ='abc@xyc.com';
         cont.Segments__c ='Business';
         cont.BU_name__c ='test1';
         cont.SPU__c =='Canada';

         insert cont;

  Case cs = new case ();
         cs.contact name = cont.id;
         cs.Type_Oyster__c = 'Ineed';
         cs.Type = 'Test1';
         cs.Request_Sub_Type__c ='test2';
         cs.Workflow__c ='test3';
         cs.Status = 'test4';
         cs.Pending_With__c ='test2';
         cs.Case Origin = 'Email';


          insert cs;
FeedItem post = new FeedItem(); post.body = '[Welcome to test Knowledge]'; Post.parentid = cs.Id;

  insert post;
```

Please can any one help me out in this .

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: Tell us atleast which lines are not getting covered or which criterias are not getting met

Comment: @Prady..Invalid field Workflow__c for SObject Contact ... in the cs.workflow__c='test';..

Comment: is `workflow__c` on the Case or the Contact record? In your code you say it is on Case but the previous comment says the problem is on Contact. Confusing.

Comment: yeah ..its on case .. i have quotes in the \\workflow__c and //cs.Pending_With__c ='xyc'.. jus am looking for meet class method coverage in the feeditem post..

Comment: @Satish- still confused - you said error is `Invalid field Workflow__c for SObject Contact`. When you insert the Case, is there a trigger on Case that tries to update the Case's Contact.Workflow__c ? And that field doesn't exist on the Contact?  That is, you aren't even getting far enough to insert the Feeditem

Comment: Check that System admin has the appropriate permissions to the field - if the field was deployed and not created in the UI - you may need to adjust the permissions manually if the profile permissions were not as well deployed